# Вопрос по JSON и JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть json файл. Как его содержание перенести на html страницу в браузер с помощью javascript?

Comment: А где файл? Что значит "перенести"?

Comment: @entithat Файл с сообщениями. Мне нужно перенести его содержимое на html страницу. Возможно ли это?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```js
fetch('./data.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => /* ваш код */)
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err));
```