# Как можно загрузить картинки на страницу из json файла c url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите пожалуйста как загрузить картинки из json файла страницу.Есть json файл с url изображений и размерами (файл показан на картинке). Нужно что-бы при клике на кнопку открыть я выбирал файл json и выводил картинки на страницу по url.

```js
upload('#file', {
    multi: true,
    accept: ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.json']
});


function upload(selector, options = {}) {
    let files = [];
    const input = document.querySelector(selector);
    const preview = document.querySelector('.preview');

    const open = document.createElement('button');
    open.classList.add('btn');
    open.textContent = 'Открыть';

    if(options.multi) {
        input.setAttribute('multiple', true)
    }

    if(options.accept && Array.isArray(options.accept)) {
        input.setAttribute('accept', options.accept.join(','))
    }

    
    input.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', open);

    const triggerInput = () => input.click(); 

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        if(!event.target.files.length) {
            return
        }
        files = Array.from(event.target.files)

        files.forEach(file => {
            if (!file.type.match('image')) {
                return
            }
          
            const reader = new FileReader()

            reader.onload = ev => {
                const src = ev.target.result
                preview.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
                <div class="preview-image">
                    <div class="preview-remove" data-name="${file.name}">&times;</div>
                    <img src="${src}" alt="${file.name}" />
                </div>
                `)
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        })

    }

    const removeHandler = event => {
        if(!event.target.dataset.name) {
            return
        }

        const {name} = event.target.dataset
        files = files.filter(file => file.name !== name)

        const block = preview.querySelector(`[data-name="${name}"]`)
        .closest('.preview-image')

        block.remove()
    }

    open.addEventListener('click', triggerInput);
    input.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
    preview.addEventListener('click', removeHandler);
};
```

```css
.main {
    max-width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.btn {
    color: rgb(73, 156, 224);
    position: relative;   
    border: 2px solid rgb(73, 156, 224);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.btn.primary {                              
    background: rgb(73, 156, 224);    
    color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.active {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
input[type=file] {
    display: none;
}
.preview {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.preview-image {
    position: relative;
    height: 20vh;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.preview-image:last-child {
    flex-grow: 10;
}
.preview-image img {
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.preview-image img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.preview-image:hover .preview-remove {
    opacity: 1;
}
.preview-remove {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .22s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <input type="file" id="file">
   <div class="preview">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Механизм не сложный

Используем цикл for

Я поясню что происходит: полный url картинки такой [http://placehold.it/размер/цвет](http://placehold.it/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80/%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)

такой api даёт сервис placehold.it я просто разбил по состовляющим и это видно из object из которого я по порядку вывоижу `src + fill` `width` `height` `alt`

```js
let gallery = [{
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  url: "http://placehold.it/640x480",
  fill: "9ca",
  alt: "Первое изображение"
}, {
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  url: "http://placehold.it/640x480",
  fill: "9ff",
  alt: "Второе изображение"
}]
let html = "";
for (gal in gallery) {
  html += `<img src="${gallery[gal].url}/${gallery[gal].fill}" width="${gallery[gal].width}px" height="${gallery[gal].height}px" alt="${gallery[gal].alt}">`;
}

document.querySelector(".body").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это понял. Но как мне найти добраться к этому url , если он вообще находиться в другом файле.Как мне указать этот путь в моем коде, когда я буду кликать на кнопку "открыть" и выбирать json файл?

Comment: @fron321 через fetch как в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1258674/308951

Comment: @fron321 https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qBqvLzK - вот подробнее - открой там console